# New changed category name is not showing on storefront

Tags: category, frontend, magento-2.1.7

I changed a category name from **ABC** to **XYZ**. After saving the category, XYZ is showing in admin section but on frontend old **ABC** is showing.

I reindex the store and also clean the cache but the changes not seen on storefront.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento version is maintained in the tags

Comment: in your magento multiple store available?

Comment: No, I have a single store mode available, but for the testing I enable multistore mode but this also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solve this myself.

Issue  is related to the some database glitch, changed value is changed for the Admin but Not for the Frontend(store_id = 1).